# Will application of Anchor seal on a daily basis after doing some carving (for a 30" red cedar mask) provide any likely benefit?

Tags: carving

My 30" cedar round is 3years old, cut down the middle for 3 months. All sides coated with Thompsons water seal for one year. Split round had zero checks until one week ago, now several 1" exterior checks. Need to start this carving, I'm wondering if I reseal new exposed carved wood would this do any good, and what other preventitive measures can I take?

Comment: Without any direct experience of this I think this is firmly in the *try it and see* category! No amount of armchair theorising is going to confidently predict what'll happen here.

Comment: Can I just clarify, you had a thick round that you then sliced into two thinner rounds after it had been drying for three years? *"All sides coated with Thompsons water seal for one year."* Do you literally mean all sides, or just all the end-grain surfaces? While Thompson's Water Seal ≠ Anchorseal coating the entire surface would be counterproductive.

Comment: Hi Graphus, thank you. To clarify, the round is 30" tall. tree trunk is 21". I coated end grains for a yr, cut lengthwise into 2 semi rounds, removed bark. Coated the face cut, did not coat where bark was.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I cut the round lenghtwise, into two half rounds, coated all cut sides.

Comment: Started carving. Will coat daily w water seal (its what I have on hand) I'll report next month with results.

Comment: Something that only occurred to me later, is there a reason this project couldn't have been done starting from cedar boards? In addition to not having to worry about the drying and related cracking you wouldn't have to carve so much into an end-grain surface.

Comment: The mask is 8" thick by 20 x18 after several days work. I dont have equipment to laminate expertly, but dry wood really wood be best. Many of my carvings are lite relief on boards, but this is a moon mask, Haida style. Check out Klathe-bhi carvings for moon masks.